# What's the difference between camera mapping and UV unwrapping?

Tags: texturing, uv, camera

I came across the term 'Camera mapping' and searched for some tutorials. I found that it's just pasting the images on objects, very much like UV unwrapping.

So what *is* the difference?

Comment: Camera mapping is the most often mispresented camera matching but the actual camera mapping is well explained here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B9r9tKX5olY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular uv-unwrapping:

[image]

Camera mapping:

[image]

Camera mapping is basically a type of uv-unwrapping.
In general you use regular uv-unwrapping if you want to apply a texture directly to a face, and camera mapping if you want to apply an image taken from the perspective of the (viewport) camera to an entire mesh.

Answer (score 1):

It is a method which allows you to make an illusion of moving through some real scene.
You match the virtual (Blender's) camera with the real footage camera, take a "screenshots" from the footage, edit them by a photo-editor and map those photos to Blender objects which help to mimic the real scenery. This way you can "reconstruct" the real scene and add custom CG objects into it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B9r9tKX5olY

It is often misrepresented as Camera Tracking / Matching which is a different thing.

Comment: it uv unwraps for the whole scene(that is the video I took the tut from) and what's the big difference from uv unwrapping, One thing is that you don't have to worry about the focal length to match the perspective, are there any other.

Comment: Unwrapping is just a part of the whole Camera Mapping process you need to realize to create the real scene reconstruction. And you use camera matching for that.

Answer (score 0):

Camera Mapping might reference the `Camera` output of the `Texture Coordinate` node, which provides a similar result to UV-unwrapping using `Project from view`, with the difference that it's depending on the current position of the camera in every frame and not calculated once.
[image: Texture Coordinate Node]